# Can't create database with Entity Framework code-first + no database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am studying about Entity Framework and I can do it with code first + existing database. However, when I try to create a new database with code first, it doesn't work.

Can you help me correct my code ?

```
public class QuanLySinhVien : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<SinhVien> SinhViens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class SinhVien
{
    public int SinhVienId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
}
```

and this is create code

```
var db = new QuanLySinhVien();          
        var sinhvien = new SinhVien { Name = "Test Name", Address="Address", BirthDay=DateTime.Now };
        db.SinhViens.Add(sinhvien);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

this is message

[image]

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> demoMVVM.SinhVien: : EntityType 'SinhVien' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   SinhViens: EntityType: EntitySet 'SinhViens' is based on type 'SinhVien' that has no keys defined.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
>   at demoMVVM.MainWindow.btnAdd_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in d:\LuuTru\CSharp\WPF Application\TestMVVM\demoMVVM\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 48

Comment: What does exception erorr message says?

Comment: Your model data are violate constraint on your model definition, therefore this exception occur. See inner exception for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Change your model as follow:

```
public class SinhVien
{
    [Key]
    public int SinhVienId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
}
```

You got the exception because you haven't defined `primary key` for your model. By default, EF take `Id` property as `primary key`, but if you use another name for your key, you have to explicit delcare it (in your case is `SinhVienId` and `GroupId`

**UPDATE**

You can define database name in `connectionString` inside your app.config/web.config then pass `connectionString` name to `DbContext` constructor like this:

```
<add 
name="connectionStringName" 
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\yourdbfile.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and `DbContext` constructor:

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelContext()
        : base("connectionStringName")
    {
    }
}
```

Note that `|DataDirectory|` will point to your `App_Data` folder

Comment: Thank you very much, It work correctly when i remove [ForeignKey(Name="GroupID")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }c because it do not know "Name" in [ForeignKey(Name="GroupID")]

Comment: so, if i want to setup this app to another computer. Do i need to add connectionString and convert to Entity FrameWork with existing database ? or just copy mdf file ?

Comment: What kind of database you're using? `SQL Server` or `SQL Server Compact`? If you're using `SQL Server`, you only need to point EF to your existing database via `connectionString`, but if you're using `SQL Server Compact`, you have to copy mdf file to `App_Data` folder on the other computer

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, please update your `foreign key` declaration as in the answer, you will need it in order to enable EF `Lazy Loading`

Comment: How can i define ForeignKey have same name with attribute in that class. For example: in class SinhVien we have attribute "Name" but if i want to have ForeignKey with Name in Group. How can i do it ?

Comment: you can make a property `GroupName` in your `SinhVien` class, then point `foreign key` to that property like this: `[ForeignKey("GroupName")] public virtual Group Group {get;set;}`

Comment: Note that there can't be properties with similar name in a same class, therefore, you have to create a different property name then point it to foreign key

Comment: but if we create different name, it might not connect to that property in Group class. So we should create different way: class SinhVien{.. string SinhVien_Name;..} class Group{..string Gourp_Name...} ?

Comment: Attribute `[ForeignKey("GroupName")]` tell EF that `GroupName` property of `SinhVien` class will be `foreign key` of `Name` in `Group`, therefore you don't need to create it with the way you mentioned. But if you want to keep your code clean and easy to read and understand, you can consider to use your approach

Comment: can i define name for database before i create database by code first ? You Know, code first automatic define database name, and these name are difficult to manage.

Comment: can we define local of MDF file ? for example: appdata folder in solution

Comment: Answer updated, please take a look. And next time you have a question, post it as new question instead of include it in comment of an old question, because comment section in SO are limited